# Make two divs the same height

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have two divs. One of them is automatically reduced in height on mobile devices (includes photo that is 100% width and height auto). The second div has given the css height: 400px. I would like to be removed from css the height and write in jquery. If the div first (smaller) it is 200px and the second must have a height of 200px.

Comment: show your code? what have you tried?

Comment: @TusharGupta http://jsfiddle.net/C6FSp/ On a smaller screen picture width changes, and hence its height. Initially, the two divas have 400px in height, but then # slider decreases. Then it must also decrease the second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can also try with this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var sliderHeight = $("#slider").height();
        $("#akcesoria").height(sliderHeight);
    }); 
});
```